# Classic ASP : what's wrong with my code to convert quantity from dozen to piece (eg. 10.3 dozen = 123 pieces)

Tags: asp-classic

What i want is to retrieve quantity in database from piece and covert it to dozen. Then input as dozen and convert back to pieces and save to database again.

when I input data eg. 10.3, it should convert to 123 piece for me ((10 * 12) + 3). My code work well without my "If clause" but only when data was "single" type. It made error when I input integer number, so I added "If.." statement to check it first which is now the output was correct for Integer but incorrect when I input single number.

I have this code..

```
Function DzToPcs(val)

'If CLng(val) = val then <-- not work
'if Fix(val) <> val then <-- work but the output was not correct when input single type number.
if Int(vInt) = vInt then <-- work but the output was not correct when input single type number.
    DztoPcs = val * 12
else
    strInt =  Cstr(val)
    a = Split(strInt,".")

    dz = a(0) 
    pcs = a(1)

    getdz = Cint(dz)
    getpcs = Cint(pcs)

    DztoPcs = (getdz * 12) + getpcs
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your `if` statements (my VBScript is a little rusty), but you could try this alternative:

```
Function DzToPcs(val)

    strInt =  Cstr(val)
    a = Split(strInt,".")
    dz = a(0) 

    if UBound(a) > 0 then
        pcs = a(1)
        getdz = Cint(dz)
        getpcs = Cint(pcs)
        DztoPcs = (getdz * 12) + getpcs
    else
        DztoPcs = dz * 12
    end if 

end function
```